# Nullpointer exception with dom4j on Websphere

Tags: java, websphere, rad, dom4j

I use RAD and websphere to develop a J2EE app and when I try to execute this code from DOM4J library:

```
XPath xpathSelector = DocumentHelper.createXPath("//annee[@annee='"+request.getAnnee()+ "']/offre[@nomOffre='"+request.getOffre()+"'"+conditionProfile+"]/produit[@nomProduit='"+request.getProduit()+"']/"+request.getTypeDocument() +"/specificite[@type='"+request.getSpecificite()+"']/*");
List nodes = xpathSelector.selectNodes(doc);
```

doc is a org.dom4j.Document object.

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jaxen.util.DescendantAxisIterator.hasNext(DescendantAxisIterator.java:101)
at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultStep.evaluate(DefaultStep.java:152)
at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultLocationPath.evaluate(DefaultLocationPath.java:140)
at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultAbsoluteLocationPath.evaluate(DefaultAbsoluteLocationPath.java:113)
at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultXPathExpr.asList(DefaultXPathExpr.java:102)
at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectNodesForContext(BaseXPath.java:674)
at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectNodes(BaseXPath.java:213)
at org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath.selectNodes(DefaultXPath.java:132)
at com.probtp.gp.multitarificateur.referentiel.Referentiel.constitueListePDF(Referentiel.java:250)
at com.probtp.gp.multitarificateur.referentiel.Referentiel.invoque(Referentiel.java:208)
at com.probtp.gp.multitarificateur.referentiel.Referentiel.donner_Referentiel(Referentiel.java:489)
at com.probtp.gp.multitarificateur.referentiel.Referentiel.donner_Referentiel(Referentiel.java:460)
at com.probtp.gp.simulateurs.gammemodulaire.GM_FUEModule.traitementNoticeSpecifique(GM_FUEModule.java:596)
at com.probtp.simulateurs.pdf.PdfMULTI.constitueFicheNotice(PdfMULTI.java:806)
at com.probtp.simulateurs.pdf.PdfMULTI.traiterOffre(PdfMULTI.java:525)
at com.probtp.simulateurs.pdf.PdfMULTI.genererMulti(PdfMULTI.java:407)
at com.probtp.simulateurs.pdf.PdfMULTI.constitutionPDF(PdfMULTI.java:307)
at com.probtp.gp.multitarificateur.action.ChargeMultiValidation.redirectDevis(ChargeMultiValidation.java:1433)
at com.probtp.gp.multitarificateur.action.ChargeMultiValidation.execute(ChargeMultiValidation.java:275)
at com.probtp.gp.ActionGP.perform(ActionGP.java:169)
at probtp.web.base.action.PActionBase.performAction(PActionBase.java:194)
at probtp.web.struts.PAction.perform(PAction.java:119)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionPerform(ActionServlet.java:1487)
at probtp.web.struts.PActionServlet.process(PActionServlet.java:281)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:557)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1384)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
at probtp.mesures.web.MesuresFilter.doFilter(MesuresFilter.java:281)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.probtp.web.filter.StatsFilter.doFilter(StatsFilter.java:44)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:852)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:785)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1772)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

It's not a coding issue because my team mates don't have this problem and we're supposed to have the same configuration. When I create an EAR and one of my colleagues deploy it locally it works...

I have tried the following modifications without any success :

- change the compiler from JDK 1.5 to 1.6,
- try other version of DOM4J (1.6.1 currently),
- install my server again.

If you have any tips, I would be glad to test it.

Thanks in advance, JB.

Comment: Could you please post more from the stack trace? Also check if your encoding for xml is the same as your teammates are using. To check that go to windows > preferences type in encoding on the search field. There's 2 places to check XML > XML Files and General > Content Types > Text > XML

Comment: Hello, It's not an encoding problem either, because I create a main class and test the code and it worked, I have already explorered the possibility of an encoding issue but that is not the case. I added the full trace in my first message.

Comment: Can you than check if you're using the same classloader policy as your other teammates? Also are you using the same JDK version as they are and also the same O.S? It is indeed very strange that it runs on WebSphere with no errors for your teammates and it doesn't work for you.

Comment: We have the same jdk, same OS. But I have modified the Class loader policy as you suggested from PARENT_FIRST to PARENT_LAST and it works ! If someone as an explanation it would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I've added the complete answer and explanation. Glag that it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the classloader policy to match your teammates configuration, there's a few options about how to do that the most straightforward is to change the server classloader:

Click Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name to access an application server settings page.
Specify the application class-loader policy for the application server. Save and restart.

See further details on how to change the classloader and also other approaches you can take:

[Specify class-loader values for an application server.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/trun_classload_server.html)

[Specify class-loader values for an installed enterprise application.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/trun_classload_entapp.html)

[Specify the class-loader mode for an installed web module.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/trun_classload_web.html)

The classloader policy settings are:

> **Classes loaded with parent class loader first** - Causes the class loader to search in the parent class loader first to load a class.
>   This value is the standard for Development Kit class loaders and
>   WebSphere® Application Server class loaders.
>
> **Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last**) - Causes the class loader to search in the application class loader
>   first to load a class. By specifying Classes loaded with local class
>   loader first (parent last), your application can override classes
>   contained in the parent class loader.

In short it means If you reference from your code a class in a package com.x.Foo and for instance this exactly same class is present on WebSphere classloader and also in one of your packaged libraries in your WEB-INF/lib folder if you're using the default "parent first" the classloader will find and use the WebSphere version because it will find it first on the other hand if you change it to be "parent last" it will find your libraries version first and than used it instead.
Please check the official [IBM WebSphere infocenter](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/crun_classload.html) page about where you'll find a full detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation, I was stuck for days !